# Excluding string array elements from another array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have two arrays of strings, and I need to exclude elements from one that contain elements of the second.

```
strings = ["chairs are on sale today", "my dog likes bumblebees", "one bad apple", "most snow is green"]

nouns = ["chair", "stove", "apple"]
```

the ideal result would be an array (either new or modified strings) that contains

```
["my dog likes bumblebees", "most snow is green"]
```

If this were exact matches, I could use the built-in functions:

```
result = strings - nouns
```

but obviously that won't work here.

Is there a simple way to do this, using grep, select, or some other ruby function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
strings.reject { |string| string =~ Regexp.union(nouns) }
```

Comment: or `strings.reject &Regexp.union(nouns).method(:match).to_proc`.  Not that yours isn't much better..